# If I install a mod in Minecraft Java edition, will it erase existing worlds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods

I am old and have no idea how any of this works. My son’s only Christmas request is a furniture mod for Minecraft Java edition.

If I (somehow) download and install one, will that erase his existing worlds?

I want to surprise him by building a world with furniture in because I know he’ll hop on the computer as soon as we’re done with presents on Xmas morning. I do NOT want to surprise him by inadvertently erasing all his hard work.  Help!

Answer (score 3):

No, it should not wipe out your worlds. JUST IN CASE, HOWEVER, BACKUP YOUR WORLDS.
If they do get erased, just restore the backed up worlds, and he won't be sad about losing the, because they got restored.

Comment: To backup the worlds, make a copy of the `%appdata%/.minecraft/saves/` folder, then just paste the `saves/` folder somewhere else on your computer, like your desktop or documents. If somehow something goes wrong then copy and paste the `saves/` folder back into its original spot

Answer (score -1):

No, mods will not wipe worlds, however using them incorrectly and loading the wrong version can *sometimes* cause corruption. It is best to back up a world before you load mods on it or use a different version.

you should never:

- load a modded world without all mods installed
- load a world in a previous version from its creation version

Many mods will need forge, fabric or another loader to be installed to run. this can require an installed version to be loaded (ex forge 1.12.2 rather than vanilla 1.12.2). To install a mod make sure it is in the mod folder in .minecraft and for the right version, Ex a 1.15 mod wont always work for 1.16.

i would recommend watching a few mod tutorials to make sure you get it right.